# Load external url with colorbox then truncate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, colorbox

I have been strugeling with this for a while now so I'm hopeing I can find a solution here.

I wish to open and external URL into an iframe in a colorbox popup. This is all working fine. I just want to run a post loaded function that get rid of any content (such as header and body tags) that I dont need. Here is what I have so far:

```
$('a[href*="/return-policy"]').colorbox({
        href: "/return-policy?language=" + lang,
        width: "800px",
        height: "600px",
        scrolling: false,
        iframe: true
    });
```

This returns this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>title</title>
</head>

<body>
<div>load of crap I dont need</div>
    <div class="content-content colorbox-content" id="content-content">
    THE STUFF I NEED
    </div>
<div>load of crap I dont need</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

This is all I require (in `colorbox-content` including the div `colorbox-content`):

```
<div class="content-content colorbox-content" id="content-content">
   THE STUFF I NEED
</div>
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
C

Comment: AHHH.. I can't get this to work. Anyone with any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('a[href*="/return-policy"]').colorbox({
        href: "/return-policy?language=" + lang + " #content-content",
        width: "800px",
        height: "600px",
        scrolling: false
    });
```

Comment: What Jack left unsaid (probably because he's busy) is that ColorBox uses Ajax-like syntax when acquiring external content. Note that what he added to the value of the href parameter is the ID of the Div that contains the content.  All of the other "crap" is ignored. That's basic Ajax, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
var your_result=     $("div").append($("#content-content")).html()
```

Comment: Sorry to sound daft but how would I use that?

Comment: Do you need this : `<div class="content-content colorbox-content" id="content-content">
   THE STUFF I NEED
</div>` or this : `THE STUFF I NEED` ??

Comment: `<div class="content-content colorbox-content" id="content-content"> THE STUFF I NEED </div>`

Comment: Hi @Royi I have tried to work this put but still seem to fall short somewhere. Any ideas?